# 1:1 width:height constraint to UIButton programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, aspect-ratio

How can I set the aspect ratio constraint to a 1:1 ratio of width:height on a UIButton programmatically in swift?
This image shows in Interface Builder what I want to achieve through code.

[image: My requirements in Interface Builder]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
myButton.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: myButton, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: myButton, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
```